# How spin is related to magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I know that electrons have spin for their circular motion and axial motion. But when I was reading the Magnetism I heard that "when there's magnetic field some materials get magnetized and there's some random spin of electrons for being magnetized". How spin is related to magnetism?

Is that because of electromagnetism? Electrons are electrically (negatively) charged. And for being negatively charge unpaired electrons get some random spin at random time. (But can't we talk about it using Heisenberg Uncertainty principle? According to Uncertainty principle, momentum and position can't be known together. And spin is related to motion, isn't it? If so, we actually don't know the electron has up-spin or down-spin at a specific time. We can say that they were spinning randomly(we just don't know) from the beginning or when there's no magnetic field.)

I am assuming here that there's only one electron cause, if someone takes two electrons then if one have up-spin then another will have down according to superposition (Schrodinger's cat experiment?).

Comment: Although electrons do have spin, they do not spin, in contrast to what you said in your first sentence.

Comment: This may help - [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the question is quite simple and would not require Uncertanity principle or any high advanced quantum mechanical laws for it.

To understand it we need to understand Hund's rule. Basically electron are moving around the nucleus in shells denoted by $n$. These shells are further divided by subshells and each subshell can only contain 2 electrons. Both of the electron will have opposite spins in the same subshell (study about Pauli's exclusion principle for it) so they cancel out each others effect.

This much information is sufficient for solving the problem. We don't need any type of uncertanity principle. We know a moving charge produces magnetic field. In some material like iron,cobalt and nickel (not all materials with 1 electron in their outermost shell are ferromagnetic) there is only 1 electron in their outermost subshell. As I told above when there are 2 electrons they cancel out each other effect (because the 2 electrons are moving in opposite directions the magnetic fields cancel out). When there is only one electron in a subshell, because of it motion around the nucleus and its spin it produces a net magnetic field. If all atoms are aligned in proper manner the magnetic fields add up and gives you magnetic field of material. If the atoms are not aligned properly then again the net magnetic field of atoms gets cancel out. That's the reason why all iron substance doesn't behave like a magnet.

YOUR DOUBTS:  Even if there is a uncertainty in the position and velocity, it is quite clear that electron is moving around the nucleus and that is sufficient for us (basically for creation of magnetic field).
Secondly it is possible to find the spin of a electron around the nucleus. We have done it a lot of time and don't confuse it with uncertainity principle. Thirdly, in your last passage you use used the word "superposition" which is not true for this condition. There is a rule that govern the behaviour you described about the electrons in same subshell and the rule is called Pauli's exclusion principle. You can study about it if you want.

Lastly, please don't bring Schrodinger's cat experiment into it, it's something different.

Comment: Can a person study Pauli Exclusion who don't know Lie algebra, Lie group? I don’t want to waste my time on what I can't understand. I just know some theories but no mathematical terms. So I am studying them before I get into some field theory and GR QM.

Comment: Well You cannot understand any of them without mathematics as it is very crucial in these topics.You need to have some very good hands on Mathematics.Well if you are in some smaller classes I would suggest not to study them right now but If you are in High school I will suggest you to learn Pauli's exclusion principal as it is one of the most important princpals in Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: I had mentioned some specific parts in mathematics. Cause I know multivariable-calculus and linear algebra and studying Lie algebra, Lie group. So if I can understand Pauli's Exclusion without them I would take a look. But if not then I don't want to waste my time on what I won't understand. That's why I mentioned those topics.

Comment: Well then you should study it. It is just a single statement about how fermions can be arranged.